# printf giving segmentation fault after print in schedule process function

Tags: c

my round robin schedule takes an input text file and parses it to make processes in an upcoming queue, when the computer time reaches the arrival time of a process on the upcoming queue it is enqueued into the round robin queue and scheduled on a computer core. However, when I go to schedule a process from the round robin queue it segmentation faults directly after a printf. I have no clue how to fix it, the exact point of the fault is in sched_proc function after the printf.

I've tried printing before and after, not removing from the round robin queue and just sending the head (that gives very odd output because it ends up scheduling one process on multiple cores because it isn't taken out of the queue) and nothing is working.

input.txt-

```
process ID | Service Time | Arrival Time 
t1 20 5 
t2 30 10 
t3 40 10 
t4 50 10 
t5 60 20 
t6 45 30 
t7 90 31
t9 80 32 
t10 85 33 
t11 80 34 
t12 50 40 
t13 60 50 
t14 67 55 
t15 70 57
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct core{
struct process* p; // pointer to the process currently running on this core
int proc_time; // cumulative time this process has been running on the core.
int busy;      // either 0 or 1, 0 if there is no process, 1 if there is process running on the core
};

// virtual computer struct
struct computer
{
    struct core cores[4]; //this computer has 4 cores
    long time;   // computer time in millisecond
};

// struct to store process information
struct process
{
char * process_ID;
int arrival_time;   // when this process arrives (e.g., being created)
int service_time;  // the amount of time this process needs to run on a core to finish
int io; // boolean io vlaue (C does not have bool value (c89/90), so use int to demonstrate boolean).
};

// one link in a queue that the scheduler uses to chain process structs,
// this is a standard struct to create linked list which is generally leveraged to implement queue
struct node
{
    struct process* p; // the process pointed by this link
    struct node *next; // the pointer to the next link
};


//head for the processes queue
struct node* head;
//tail for the processes queue
struct node* tail;
int proc_num; //number of processes in the queue, waiting to be scheduled and not running
int quantum; // the amount of time in milliseconds a process can run on a core before being swapped out
//struct for computer
struct computer computer;

//QUEUE STRUCT AND LOGIC
typedef struct Queue Queue;
struct Queue {
    struct node* head;
    struct node* tail;
    unsigned int process_num;
};

struct node* create_node(struct process* p) {
    struct node* node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (node) {
        node->p = p;
        node->next = NULL;
    }
    return node;
}

Queue* create_queue (void) {
    Queue* queue = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    if (queue) {
        queue->head = NULL;
        queue->tail = NULL;
        queue->process_num = 0;
    }
    return queue;
}

void clear_queue (Queue* queue) {
    struct node *current, *next;
    current = queue->head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        next = current->next;
        free(current->p->process_ID);
        free(current->p);
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }
}

void delete_queue (Queue* queue) {
    if (queue) {
        clear_queue(queue);
        free(queue);
    }
}

void print_queue (Queue* queue) {
    for (struct node* current = queue->head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
        printf("Process: %s, Arrival Time: %d, Service Time: %d, IO: %d\n", current->p->process_ID,
                current->p->arrival_time, current->p->service_time, current->p->io);
    }
}

void add_last_queue (Queue* queue, struct node* to_add) {
    if (queue->head == NULL) {
        queue->head = to_add;
        queue->tail = to_add;
    } else {
        queue->tail->next = to_add;
        queue->tail = to_add;
    }
    queue->process_num++;
}

struct process* remove_first_queue (Queue* queue) {
    struct process* data = NULL;
    if (queue->head) {
        struct node* temp = queue->head;
        if (queue->head->next) {
            queue->head = queue->head->next;
        } else {
            queue->head = NULL;
            queue->tail = NULL;
        }
        data = temp->p;
        free(temp);
        queue->process_num--;
        if (queue->process_num == 1) {
            queue->tail = queue->head;
        }
        return data;
    }
}

void rotate_queue_left (Queue* queue) {
    if (queue) {
        if (queue->head) {
            queue->tail->next = queue->head;
            queue->head = queue->head->next;
            queue->tail = queue->tail->next;
            queue->tail->next = NULL;
        }
    }
}
//END QUEUE STRUCT AND LOGIC
Queue* future_proc;
Queue* round_robin;
void read_file(void)
{
    int i,i2;
    FILE* file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    char line[90];
    char name[100];
    char service_time[3];
    char arrival_time[3];
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), file);
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        i=0;
        while(line[i]!=' '&&i<90){name[i]=line[i];i++;}
        if(i>90)break;
        name[i]=0;
        i2=++i;
        while(line[i]!=' '&&i<90){service_time[i-i2]=line[i];i++;}
        if(i>90)break;
        service_time[i]=0;
        i2=++i;
        while(line[i]!=' '&&i<90){arrival_time[i-i2]=line[i];i++;}
        if(i>90)break;
        arrival_time[i]=0;
        /* add your code here, you are to create the upcoming processes queue here.
           essentially create a node for each process and chain them in a queue.
           note this queue is *not* the process queue used for round robin scheduling
        */
                //BUILD FUTURE PROCESS QUEUE
                struct process* process;
                process = malloc(sizeof(struct process));
                process->process_ID=malloc(sizeof(50));
                strcpy(process->process_ID, name);
                process->arrival_time = atoi(arrival_time);
                process->service_time = atoi(service_time);
                process->io = 0;
                struct node* to_add = create_node(process);
                add_last_queue(future_proc, to_add);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return;
}

//this function call simulates one millisecond of time on the computer
void run_one_step(void)
{
    int i;
    computer.time++;
    printf("Processing all 4 cores, current Computer time=%lu \n",computer.time);
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(computer.cores[i].busy)
        {
            computer.cores[i].p->service_time--; // deduct the remaining service time of the running process by one millisecond
            computer.cores[i].proc_time++; // increment the running time for the process by one millisecond in current quantum
            printf("Core[%d]: %s, service_time= %d,been on core for: %d \n",i,computer.cores[i].p->process_ID,computer.cores[i].p->service_time,computer.cores[i].proc_time);


            // you need to swap out or terminate a process if it uses up the current quantum,
            // or finishes all its service time. The code for this should be located in the main()
            // function, not here.
            // Also if your code is done right, the following warning messages should never print.


            if(computer.cores[i].proc_time>quantum)
                printf("WARNING: Process on Core[%d] should not run longer than quantum\n",i);
            if(computer.cores[i].p->service_time<0)
                printf("WARNING: Process on core[%d] stayed longer than its service time.\n",i);
        }
    }
}


void run_one_step_p3(void)
{
    int rndm,i;
    computer.time++;
    printf("Processing all 4 cores, current Computer time=%lu \n",computer.time);
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(computer.cores[i].busy)
        {
            if(computer.cores[i].p->io==0)
            {
                computer.cores[i].p->service_time--;
                // with 10% probability, generate an io event
                rndm=rand()%10+1;
                if(rndm==10)computer.cores[i].p->io=1;
            }
            computer.cores[i].proc_time++;
            printf("Core[%d]: process %s, service_time= %d,been on core for: %d \n",i,computer.cores[i].p->process_ID,computer.cores[i].p->service_time,computer.cores[i].proc_time);


            // you need to swap out or terminate a process if it uses up the current quantum, has an i/o event;
            // or finishes all its service time. The code for this should be located in the main()
            // function, not here.
            // Also if your code is done right, the following warning messages should never print.

            if(computer.cores[i].p->io==1)
                printf("WARNING: Process on core[%d] has io trigerred, please remove from core, reset io signal and place it back in queue\n",i);
            if(computer.cores[i].proc_time>quantum)
                printf("WARNING: Process on Core[%d] should not run longer than quantum\n",i);
            if(computer.cores[i].p->service_time<0)
                printf("WARNING: Process on core[%d] stayed longer than its service time.\n",i);
        }
    }
}


//NOTE: you must free struct node after taking a link off the round robin queue, and scheduling the respective
// process to run on the core. Make sure you free the struct node to avoid memory leak.
void sched_proc(struct process* p,int core_id)
{
    if(computer.cores[core_id].busy==0)
    {
        printf("Process[%s] with service_time %d has been added to core %d\n",p->process_ID,p->service_time,core_id);
        computer.cores[core_id].busy=1;
        computer.cores[core_id].p=p;
        computer.cores[core_id].proc_time=0;
    }
    else printf("ERROR: must call remove_proc to remove current process before adding another to the core.\n");
}

// This handles removing a process from a core, and either discarding the process if its service_time is <=0
// or adding it to the back of the round robin queue

void remove_proc(int core_id)
{
    printf("Process[%s] at core %d has been removed from core with remaining service_time=%d\n",
    computer.cores[core_id].p->process_ID,core_id,computer.cores[core_id].p->service_time);

    // if the process has finished all its service time, terminate and clean up
    if(computer.cores[core_id].p->service_time<=0)
    {
        computer.cores[core_id].busy=0;
        // free up allocated memory for process ID and struct upon termination of a process
        free(computer.cores[core_id].p->process_ID);
        free(computer.cores[core_id].p);
        computer.cores[core_id].proc_time=0;
    }
    // the process needs to run for more time, put it back into the queue for future scheduling
    else
    {
        computer.cores[core_id].proc_time=0;
        // reinsert back to the queue
        if(round_robin->tail==NULL)
        {
            // in case queue is empty, i.e. all nodes struct were freed and there are no processes in the queue, this will become the first one
            round_robin->tail=round_robin->head=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            round_robin->head->p=computer.cores[core_id].p;
            round_robin->head->next=NULL;
            round_robin->process_num++;
            computer.cores[core_id].busy=0;
        }
        else
        {

            round_robin->tail->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            round_robin->tail=tail->next;
            round_robin->tail->p=computer.cores[core_id].p;
            round_robin->tail->next=NULL;
            round_robin->process_num++;
            computer.cores[core_id].busy=0;
        }
    }
}

// a demo running 4 processes until they're finished. The scheduling is done explicitly, not using
// a scheduling algorithm. This is just to demonstrate how processes will be scheduled. In main()
// you need to write a generic scheduling algorithm for arbitrary number of processes.
void demo(void)
{
    int i;
    struct process *p0,*p1,*p2,*p3;
    p0=malloc(sizeof(struct process));
    p1=malloc(sizeof(struct process));
    p2=malloc(sizeof(struct process));
    p3=malloc(sizeof(struct process));

    p0->process_ID=malloc(sizeof(50));//you can assume process ID will never exceed 50 characters
    p1->process_ID=malloc(sizeof(50));
    p2->process_ID=malloc(sizeof(50));
    p3->process_ID=malloc(sizeof(50));

    strcpy(p0->process_ID,"first");
    strcpy(p1->process_ID,"Second");
    strcpy(p2->process_ID,"Third");
    strcpy(p3->process_ID,"Fourth");

    //assign arrival time
    p0->arrival_time=0;
    p1->arrival_time=0;
    p2->arrival_time=0;
    p3->arrival_time=0;

    //assign service time
    p0->service_time=16;
    p1->service_time=17;
    p2->service_time=19;
    p3->service_time=21;

    p0->io = 0;
    p1->io = 0;
    p2->io = 0;
    p3->io = 0;

    // Queue* queue = create_queue();
    // add_last_queue(queue, create_node(p0));
    // add_last_queue(queue, create_node(p1));
    // add_last_queue(queue, create_node(p2));
    // add_last_queue(queue, create_node(p3));
    // printf("\nDemo queue:\n");
    // print_queue(queue);
    //
    // remove_first_queue(queue);
    // remove_first_queue(queue);
    // remove_first_queue(queue);
    // remove_first_queue(queue);
    // printf("After removing:");
    // print_queue(queue);

    // we will skip queue construction here because it's just 4 processes.
    // you must use the round robin queue for the scheduling algorithm for generic cases where many processes
    // exist and may need more than one quantum to finish


    // xx 4 processes are waiting to be scheduled. No queue is built in demo for simplicity.
    // in your generic algorithm, you should create actual queues, and proc_num should be the number of processes whose
    // arrival time has come, and are waiting in the round robin queue to be scheduled.
    proc_num=4;


    //schedule process to each core
    sched_proc(p0,0);
    sched_proc(p1,1);
    sched_proc(p2,2);
    sched_proc(p3,3);

    for(i=0;i<16;i++)run_one_step();
    remove_proc(0);
    run_one_step();
    remove_proc(1);
    run_one_step();
    run_one_step();
    remove_proc(2);
    run_one_step();
    remove_proc(3);
    sched_proc(head->p,0);

    //NOTE: you must free struct node after scheduling the process. The demo code is not doing it here
    // for simplification, but you have to do it in your code or you will have memory leakage

    //head==tail since it was the only one added now to remove it we just make pointer pointing to NULL
    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;
    run_one_step();
    remove_proc(0);
    printf("DONE\n");
}

void init(void)
{
    quantum=20;
    future_proc = create_queue();
    round_robin = create_queue();
    // head=tail=NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    init();
    // printf("\t*******Starting Demo*******\n");
  //demo();
    // printf("\t*******Reading Input*******\n");
    //
    // printf("Start file read:\n");
    // printf("End file read.\n");

    /* your code goes here for part2. In part 2, you create one node for each process, and put them on an
     * 'upcoming process' queue first. Then your code calls run_one_step(), for each process whose arrival time
     * has come, take the node off the 'upcoming process' queue, and place it on round robin queue. For each
     * process that's selected to run on a core, take the node off round robin queue.
     *
     * Repeat run_one_step() until all processes finish. Please handle memory allocation/deallocation properly so there's no leak
     */

        read_file();
        printf("\nBuilt Queue After File Read:\n");
        print_queue(future_proc);
        printf("\nProcess Num: %d\n", future_proc->process_num);
        while (future_proc->process_num > 0 /*|| round_robin->process_num > 0*/) {
             while (future_proc->process_num > 0 && computer.time == future_proc->head->p->arrival_time) {
                 struct node* to_add = create_node(remove_first_queue(future_proc));
                 add_last_queue(round_robin, to_add);
                 printf("Process %s added at time %ld\n", to_add->p->process_ID, computer.time);
                 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                     if (computer.cores[i].busy == 1) {
                         //thead process time exceeded quantum or is finished
                         if (computer.cores[i].proc_time > quantum || computer.cores[i].p->service_time <= 0) {
                             remove_proc(i);
                         }
                     }
                     if (computer.cores[i].busy == 0) { //the core is not busy
                         sched_proc(round_robin->head->p, i);
                         remove_first_queue(round_robin);
                     }
                 }
             }
             run_one_step();
        }

     printf("\nAfter adding at each step to round_robin queue:\n");
     print_queue(round_robin);





    /* After part 2 is done, you clean up everything, e.g., freeing up all memory allocated,
     * reset queues to empty etc.
     * Then restart for part 3: read input file for all processes, initialize queues,
     *  run processes using run_one_step_p3() so random i/o event can happen at each step on each core,
     *  until all processes finish. Remember to clean up again at the end!
     */




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is in input.txt?  If I try to run it I get a segfault because I don't have the file.  You're not checking the return value of fopen()  in the read_file() function, so it may be something as simple on your end.  Have you tried running your program in a debugger?

Comment: I can't format it one second

Comment: just put it in! @Shawn

Comment: After testing it with some sample entries, it's crashing in GDB (and presumably outide GDB)
 because round_robin->head is still somehow null when you call sched_proc on line 443

Comment: You need to spend more effort to isolate your problem into something that you can demonstrate in a much smaller program. By the time you do that, you may have figured out how to solve your own problem. But, if not, then the smaller program would be the candidate to bring here for trouble shooting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I just printed the process in main after: struct node* to_add = create_node(remove_first_queue(future_proc)); and it isn't null I don't know how it is null when being dereferenced @Shawn

Comment: `struct node* node = malloc(sizeof(node));` (being `sizeof (a_pointer)`), did you mean `struct node* node = malloc(sizeof(*node));`? Which is another good reason the `'*'` goes with the variable, not the type, e.g. `struct node *node ...`

Comment: `sizeof(struct node)` and `sizeof(node)` is not the same thing.

Comment: yeah i fixed that as well! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: regarding the function: `remove_first_queue()`  in one of the execution paths it returns a pointer to a sturct, BUT that struct is a local variable which goes 'out of scope'  when the function exits  AND only one of the execution paths returns a `struct process*`  There is the `false condition of the first `if()` statement that returns nothing.  Both conditions need to be fixed

Comment: there are two places in the posted code where the function: `remove_first_queue()` is called.  Both places fail to properly handle the returned value

Comment: in function: `create_queue()` when the call to `malloc()` fails, should let the user know, probably via a call to `perror( "malloc for struct queue failed" );`

Comment: in function `init()`, check (!=NULL) both `future_proc` and `round_robin`  if either is NULL, then call `free()` for the other one and exit the program, via: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed via the header file: `stdlib.h`

Comment: when calling C library functions, always check for errors and if an error if found, call `perror()` so both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred are output to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `for(i=0;i<16;i++)run_one_step();`  for ease or readability and understaning: 1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` `realloc()`, 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) do not continue the program when such a call fails

Comment: regarding: `p0->process_ID=malloc(sizeof(50));//you can assume process ID will never exceed 50 characters` and similar statements:  1) there is no object `50` so the parameter should be a simple `50`, (no `sizeof` as the size of an 'int' is (depending on the underlying hardware architecture) either 4 or 8 bytes)  2) the process ID is a char array, so with an allocation of 50, the max length of the process ID is only 49, to allow for the trailing NUL byte

Comment: there are other problems in the posted code, but the above should get you started in the right direction and thinking about what the code is actually doing

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting this in an answer simply because I can't format a comment, but this is a partial answer anyway.  When I run this program in gdb, it's gets so far and then:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
main () at scheduler.c:443
443                              sched_proc(round_robin->head->p, i);
(gdb) backtrace 
#0  main () at scheduler.c:443
```

As you see gdb is saying you crashed in the call to sched_proc().  Inspecting the value of round_robin, we can see that round_robin itself is a valid object, but its pointers are still set to NULL

```
(gdb) print *round_robin 
$1 = {head = 0x0, tail = 0x0, process_num = 0}
(gdb) quit
```

As to why that is, you may have to think a bit or learn to use a debugger to step through code (an IDE will help make this easier)

edit: Here's a hint, if you add a printf in the for loop there, it will be nulled out in the second round:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         printf("i = %i, round_robin->head, tail: %p, %p\n", i, round_robin->head, round_robin->tail);
```

Output:

```
i = 0, round_robin->head, tail: 0x55555555b520, 0x55555555b520
Process[t1] with service_time 20 has been added to core 0 
i = 1, round_robin->head, tail: (nil), (nil)
```

Comment: I suck... Thank you so much @Shawn YOU ARE MY FAVORITE PERSON ON THE INTERNET.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps other problems, yet allocation is the wrong size.

```
// struct node* node = malloc(sizeof(node));  // size of a pointer
struct node* node = malloc(sizeof *node);     // size of what `node` points to.
```

---

Also suggest

```
// Queue* queue = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
Queue* queue = malloc(sizeof *queue);
```

Or in general:

```
// ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptr_type));
ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
```